# Is there a way to swap objects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, smartobject

In Photoshop CS6 I have a lot of (smart) objects perfectly spaced out but in the wrong order.
All the objects are the same size.

Is there a way to swap the location of a object with another one?
Would save me loads of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: judging by the questions you posted today, I get the impression that your job is better suited to be done in InDesign rather than Photoshop. Is this an option? ID has way more tools for things like this.

Comment: Well I already started to shuffle them by hand. But next time I think I'll choose Indesign indeed.

Comment: The swaping could be scripted yes. If you have lots of objects its faster to write the script than do manual work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forever doing this with catalogues and the like!

You could do this quick and dirty by keeping the right and left most smart objects where they are, these are going to keep the edge boundaries. Then re-jig the ones in the middle and then select the right and left ones mentioned earlier along with the rejig ones, Align to Top/Vertical Align, and then 'Distribute Horizontal Centers'

If you needed to swap the Right and Left boundary images, do this first, just by moving the ones you do want, ontop and with 'Snap to' on they should just click into place.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this from my experience **for an image** is to turn that image into a smart object and relink that to the desired image you want to replace it with. Anything other than that you're pushing PS in a direction better suited for ID.

Good luck!